Perfect squares cross-number
Put a single digit in each cell of the grid below so that every number formed by reading across rows or down columns is a perfect square.
Here's the fine print. We do not allow leading 0's. Using a given perfect square more than once is okay.


Attribution:  Erich Friedman

The answer is: .....................

 

Below is my thought process:

 step 1. Focus on the right above part of the grid. I consider a 'black box':
 
 If there are two ordered pair $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ satisfy the above 'black box', which means: the numbers formed by ordered triplets $(a,X1,X3)$, $(b,X2,X4)$, $(c,X1,X2)$ and $(d,X3,X4)$ are all 'perfect square'. Then we say $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ have some kind of relation, denoted as $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$. For example, $$(1,1)\sim(1,1) \quad\quad (4,4)\sim(7,4)\quad\quad ......$$ However, there is no need to list all the relation pairs, because the number formed by pair $(a,b)$ should be a two-digit 'perfect square'. So we only need to list the relations relevant to the pairs below: $$(1,6) \quad (2,5) \quad (3,6) \quad (4,9) \quad (6,4) \quad (8,1)$$...... Coincidentally, only the following relation pairs are satisfied: $$ \begin{array}{ccc} (4,9)\sim(1,4) & (4,9)\sim(4,9) & (4,9)\sim(9,1) \\  (4,9)\sim(4,1) & (4,9)\sim(9,4) & (4,9)\sim(1,9) \\ (4,9)\sim(1,1) & (4,9)\sim(4,4) & (4,9)\sim(9,9) \\ \end{array}$$ ...
 
 Then, I consider that the ordered triplets $(c,d,?)$ should be a three-digit 'perfect square', so now we can delete some relation pairs from the above result. Only the below two pairs left: $$(4,9)\sim(1,4) \quad\quad (4,9)\sim(4,4)$$
 We have two schemes as below:
 

step 2. Focus on the left below part of the grid. We need some two-digit to 'perfect squares' to finish this part. And we need the 'end to end pairs' $(1,6)\rightarrow(6,4)$, $(3,6)\rightarrow(6,4)$ and $(8,1)\rightarrow(1,6)$ to deal with the 'grid corner'. We have three  schemes as below:
 

In the end, combine the possible schemes of step 1 and step 2, we can derive the unique solution of this puzzle.


Could you add a bit of explanation on how you found this solution? What was your way into it?

Isn't this solution partially incorrect? The statement stipulates that leading 0s are not permitted.

@Foxy. There are no leadig zeros

@Marius Ah, yes. My bad, I'd misread the question.

@JaapScherphuis I've updated my answer, please check.

@RobPratt Thanks! Now updated.

Interesting analysis. I started at the bottom left block, finding only a few possibilities. Looking at the first digit on the middle row, considering the two squares it is part of and the fact that horizontally it must be followed by two square-ending digits, narrowed it down enough to find a single solution.

Below is python code using Google's ORTools and constraint programming to solve the problem.

#!pip install ortools

from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
import numpy as np

# Creates the model and set solver
model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

n = 5

x = {(i,j): model.NewIntVar(0,9,f'x_{i}_{j}') for i in range(n) for j in range(n)}
val = {i: model.NewIntVar(1,100,f'val_{i}') for i in range(n*2)}
y = {i: model.NewIntVar(1,1000,f'y_{i}') for i in range(n*2)}

model.Add(y[0] == 10*x[3,0] + x[4,0])
model.Add(y[1] == 10*x[3,1] + x[4,1])
model.Add(y[2] == 100*x[1,2] + 10*x[2,2] + x[3,2])
model.Add(y[3] == 100*x[0,3] + 10*x[1,3] + x[2,3])
model.Add(y[4] == 100*x[0,4] + 10*x[1,4] + x[2,4])

model.Add(y[5] == 10*x[0,3] + x[0,4])
model.Add(y[6] == 100*x[1,2] + 10*x[1,3] + x[1,4])
model.Add(y[7] == 100*x[2,2] + 10*x[2,3] + x[2,4])
model.Add(y[8] == 100*x[3,0] + 10*x[3,1] + x[3,2])
model.Add(y[9] == 10*x[4,0] + x[4,1])

for i in range(n*2):
    model.AddMultiplicationEquality(y[i], [val[i], val[i]])

leading = [(3,0),(3,1),(2,2),(1,2),(0,3),(0,4)]

for i,j in x:
    if (i,j) in leading:
        model.Add(x[i,j] != 0)

status = solver.Solve(model)

print(f"Status = {solver.StatusName(status)}")

np.reshape([solver.value(x[i,j]) for i,j in x],(n,n))

As tToE has shown,

 

is correct.

(4,0) is also leading.
